# Java button going to wrong place in code.

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement

so i'm making a project for my science class but the questions arent working. What im trying to do is when i click the answer for the first question i want it to go to the 2nd question but it goes to the last question instead. I am very new to java (i started last week) but i do have basic experience in other languages. I would appreciate any help i could get, thank you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Window {

    JFrame window;
    Container con;
    JPanel titlenamePanel, startButtonPanel, mainTextPanel, ChoiceButtonPanel;
    JLabel titlenameLabel;
    Font titleFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    JButton startButton, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6;
    JTextArea mainTextArea;
    String Progress, yourChoice, Wind, Rain, Location, Cloud;
    int Temp, Hum;


    TitleScreenHandler tsHandler = new TitleScreenHandler();
    ChoiceHandler chandler = new ChoiceHandler();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        new Window();
    }

        public Window(){

            window = new JFrame();
            //width x height
            window.setSize(800, 600);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
            window.setLayout(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
            con = window.getContentPane();

            titlenamePanel = new JPanel();
            titlenamePanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 150);
            titlenamePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
            titlenameLabel = new JLabel("Weather Genie");
            titlenameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            titlenameLabel.setFont(titleFont);

            startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
            startButtonPanel.setBounds(300, 400, 200, 100);
            startButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);

            startButton = new JButton("Start");
            startButton.setBackground(Color.black);
            startButton.setForeground(Color.white);
            startButton.setFont(normalFont);
            startButton.addActionListener(tsHandler);

            titlenamePanel.add(titlenameLabel);
            startButtonPanel.add(startButton);

            con.add(titlenamePanel);
            con.add(startButtonPanel);

        }

        public void createWindowScreen() {

            titlenamePanel.setVisible(false);
            startButtonPanel.setVisible(false);
            // Text Panel
            mainTextPanel = new JPanel();
            mainTextPanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 250);
            mainTextPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
            con.add(mainTextPanel);
            // Add Texts 
            mainTextArea = new JTextArea("Please answer the following questions.");
            mainTextArea.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 250);
            mainTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
            mainTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);
            mainTextArea.setFont(normalFont);
            mainTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
            mainTextPanel.add(mainTextArea);
            // Button Panel
            ChoiceButtonPanel = new JPanel();
            ChoiceButtonPanel.setBounds(250, 350, 300, 150);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
            con.add(ChoiceButtonPanel);
            // Buttons
            choice1 = new JButton("Choice 1");
            choice1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice1.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice1.setFont(normalFont);
            choice1.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice1);
            choice1.setActionCommand("c1");
            choice2 = new JButton("Choice 2");
            choice2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice2.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice2.setFont(normalFont);
            choice2.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice2);
            choice2.setActionCommand("c2");
            choice3 = new JButton("Choice 3");
            choice3.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice3.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice3.setFont(normalFont);
            choice3.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice3);
            choice3.setActionCommand("c3");
            choice4 = new JButton("Choice 4");
            choice4.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice4.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice4.setFont(normalFont);
            choice4.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice4);
            choice4.setActionCommand("c4");
            choice5 = new JButton("Choice 5");
            choice5.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice5.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice5.setFont(normalFont);
            choice5.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice5);
            choice5.setActionCommand("c5");
            choice6 = new JButton("Choice 6");
            choice6.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            choice6.setForeground(Color.white);
            choice6.setFont(normalFont);
            choice6.addActionListener(chandler);
            ChoiceButtonPanel.add(choice6);
            choice6.setActionCommand("c6");
            varSetup();
        }   

        public void varSetup() {
            Temp = 80;
            Hum = 65; 
            Location = "South";
            Rain = "No";
            Wind = "No";
            Cloud = "Clear";
            CloudQuestion();
        }

        public void CloudQuestion(){
            Progress = "CloudQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("What do the clouds look like?");
            choice1.setText("High and Dark");
            choice2.setText("High and Bright");
            choice3.setText("Low and Dark");
            choice4.setText("Low and Bright");
            choice5.setText("Clear");
            choice6.setText("Foggy");
        }
        public void TempQuestion(){
            Progress = "TempQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("What tmperature is it outside?");
            choice1.setText("90-110");
            choice2.setText("70-89");
            choice3.setText("50-69");
            choice4.setText("30-49");
            choice5.setText("10-29");
            choice6.setText("0-10");
        }
        public void HumQuestion() {
            Progress = "HumQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("How Humid is it outside? \nEx. The Average Household humidity is 65");
            choice1.setText("90-100");
            choice2.setText("70-89");
            choice3.setText("50-69");
            choice4.setText("30-49");
            choice5.setText("10-29");
            choice6.setText("");
            }
        public void WindQuestion(){
            Progress = "WindQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("Has it been windy outside today?");
            choice1.setText("Yes");
            choice2.setText("No");
            choice3.setText("");
            choice4.setText("");
            choice5.setText("");
            choice6.setText("");
            }
        public void RainQuestion() {
            Progress = "RainQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("Has it Rained this week?");
            choice1.setText("1-2 Times");
            choice2.setText("3-4 Times");
            choice3.setText("5 or more Times");
            choice4.setText("None");
            choice5.setText("");
            choice6.setText("");
            }
        public void LocQuestion() {
            Progress = "LocQ";
            mainTextArea.setText("What part of the US are you in? \nExample, florida would be East \nSomebody in Nebraska or Kansas would say Central. ");
            choice1.setText("North");
            choice2.setText("South");
            choice3.setText("East");
            choice4.setText("West");
            choice5.setText("Central");
            choice6.setText("");
            }

        public class ChoiceHandler implements ActionListener{

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                String yourChoice = event.getActionCommand();

                switch (Progress) {
                case "CloudQ": 
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1":
                            Cloud = "HD";
                            TempQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c2":
                            Cloud = "HB";
                            TempQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c3":
                            Cloud = "LD";
                            TempQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c4":
                            Cloud = "LB";
                            TempQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c5":
                            Cloud = "Clear";
                            TempQuestion();  
                            break;
                        case"c6":
                            Cloud = "Foggy";
                            TempQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                case "TempQ": 
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1":
                            Temp = 90110;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c2":
                            Temp = 7089;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c3":
                            Temp = 5069;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c4":
                            Temp = 3049;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c5":
                            Temp = 1029;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c6":
                            Temp = 010;
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                case "HumQ":
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1": 
                            Hum = 90100; WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c2": 
                            Hum = 7089; WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c3": 
                            Hum = 5069; WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c4": 
                            Hum = 3049; WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c5": 
                            Hum = 1029; 
                            WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c6": 
                            HumQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                case "WinQ":
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1": 
                            Wind = "Yes"; 
                            RainQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c2": 
                            Wind = "No"; 
                            RainQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c3": 
                            WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c4": 
                            WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c5": 
                            WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c6": 
                            WindQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                case "RainQ":
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1": 
                            Rain = "12"; 
                            LocQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c2": 
                            Rain = "34"; 
                            LocQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c3": 
                            Rain = "5+"; 
                            LocQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c4": 
                            Rain = "None"; 
                            LocQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c5": 
                            RainQuestion();
                            break;
                        case"c6": 
                            RainQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                case "LocQ":
                    switch(yourChoice) {
                        case"c1": 
                            Location = "North"; results();break;
                        case"c2": 
                            Location = "South"; results();break;
                        case"c3": 
                            Location = "East"; results();break;
                        case"c4": 
                            Location = "West"; results();break;
                        case"c5": 
                            Location = "Central"; results();break;
                        case"c6": 
                            LocQuestion();
                            break;
                        }
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        public void results() {

        }
        public class TitleScreenHandler implements ActionListener{

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                createWindowScreen();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you want us to debug for you.  Consider this a good learning opportunity for *you* to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and directly observe the changing runtime values of your variables, runtime behavior of your logic, etc.  When you do this, where specifically does the behavior change from what you expected it to do?  Which specific operation or line of code produced an unexpected result.  What were the values?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Title is misleading, try editing it to a specfic one.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or ..

Comment: .. [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a switch statement inside another switch statement, in the inner switch statement you're correctly using `break`, however you're never breaking after the inner switch statement, see the code below (only a part of your code) to see what you're missing. I've marked the `break` statements with `// Add this`.

Not using the `break` there is causing it to execute every `case` under the `case` that it matched against. It will do so until the first `break` is reached or the `switch` has ended.

```
switch (Progress) {
case "CloudQ":
    switch (yourChoice) {
    case "c1":
        Cloud = "HD";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    case "c2":
        Cloud = "HB";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    case "c3":
        Cloud = "LD";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    case "c4":
        Cloud = "LB";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    case "c5":
        Cloud = "Clear";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    case "c6":
        Cloud = "Foggy";
        TempQuestion();
        break;
    }
    break; // Add this
case "TempQ":
    switch (yourChoice) {
    case "c1":
        Temp = 90110;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    case "c2":
        Temp = 7089;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    case "c3":
        Temp = 5069;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    case "c4":
        Temp = 3049;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    case "c5":
        Temp = 1029;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    case "c6":
        Temp = 010;
        HumQuestion();
        break;
    }
    break; // Add this
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Mark you are a life saver. I dont know what i woulve done without you. I will 100% credit you in my science fair. You are a saint <3